# How to root Teac Tc-7120

Tags: rooting

I want to root my new Teac TC-7120 device, but couldn't find any rooting guide targeting it.

What should I do?

I used the following Guide:
http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/root-android-phone-superoneclick-2/

But even though my device is connected and in Debugging mode, I can't get the ADB to recognize it.

Comment: if you are using windows (which I assume you are since you mentioned using superoneclick), you will need the USB drivers for the device, otherwise ADB will not recognize the device.

Comment: Where can I get the driver? I guess you mean the "Install Drivers" option that appears when I connect my tablet. I've tried it, but no response from the computer.

Comment: The device tried to installed the driver but it says it is already installed.\

Comment: @RyanConrad Is it possible to clean the device completely and install a vanilla version of android 4.3 on him? (Like I would re-format a computer's hard-drive and install an OS on him).

Comment: consult the [rooting index](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1184/how-do-i-root-my-android-device?lq=1) and try the rooting apps. Kingoroot haven't failed me yet, USB debug mode is the only requirement,

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about rooting your device, but I can help with getting your device to be recognised by your computer.

Exact instructions will depend on what OS you are running, but basically you need to find the .android folder in your home directory, and replace the adb_usb.ini file [with this one](https://raw.github.com/apkudo/adbusbini/master/adb_usb.ini).  this tells your computer to let adb work with a load of different usb devices.  You may need to type this on the command line to get it to work after you do this:

```
adb kill-server
adb start-server
```

and now running this should show you your device

```
adb devices
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to download and install framaroot in to your device I think that should work 
Link:http://m.apkhere.com/app/com.alephzain.framaroot

Answer (score 0):

Install king user it's a Chinese rooting program just continue clicking the blue button this program can root nearly any android device and works fine no bricking
And no computer needed only your phone

Comment: Can you provide a link for "king user", please.